# Responsive Youtube Background v.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Vaughn D. Taylor created this amazing codepen to use Youtube as a (repsonsive) background video. Everything works perfect but I do get a Error in the console of Chrome. I was wondering if anyone knows why this is and/or has a solution! (It doesn't effect the JS because it does work but maybe it just nice to have this fixed)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of null
  at Y.h.setSize (www-widgetapi.js:83)
  at vidRescale (all.js:2)
  at all.js:2
  at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
  at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I'm loading in jQuery 2.2.4 before the body closing tag, all.js is my JS file with the JS code that I got from the codepen. It is loaded after the jQuery.

**Responsive Youtube Background 4.2:**

https://codepen.io/vaughndtaylor/pen/QNYRdb

Comment: Does it actually affect the user experience? Errors are common on production standard websites, in fact you'd be hard pressed to find a big site without errors in the console.

Comment: No it doesn't, it would just be nice if there was an (easy) solution :) also to learn from it myself